# Logstash memory heap issues

Tags: logstash

I am trying to ingest JSON records using logstash but am running into memory issues. Previously our pipeline could run with default settings (memory queue, batch size 125, one worker per core) and process 5k events per second. We added some data to the JSON records and now the heap memory goes up and gradually falls apart after one hour of ingesting.

[image: monitoring graphs]

What I have tried to improve this is:

1. Increase memory via options in docker-compose to "LS_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx8g -Xms8g". The virtual machine has 16GB of memory.
2. Switched to a persistent queue.
3. Lowered pipeline batch size from 125 down to 75.

While these have helped, it just delays the time until the memory issues start to occur. Any ideas on what I should do to fix this? Should I increase the memory some more? Should I increase the size of the persistent queue? I am at my wits end!

Edit: Here is another image of memory usage after reducing pipeline works to 6 and batch size to 75:

[image: second logstash graph]

Comment: Update your question with your full pipeline configuration, the input, filters and output. Also, can you share what did you added to the json data and what does your message looks now and before? What version are you using and how many cores do your server have?

Comment: @leandrojmp I added that info.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who runs into this and is using a lot of different field names, my problem was due to an issue with logstash [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/10112) that will be fixed in version 7.17. Logstash is caching field names and if your events have a lot of unique field names, it will cause out of memory errors like in my attached graphs.